# Inherit Windows ThreadHandle

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi, winapi

I just realized that it is NOT possible to Suspend/Resume/Terminate a thread OUTSIDE its own application (address space?!) if you know the right ThreadHandle Value for it... As far as I guess you will not be able to use `WaitForSingleObject` either.
However I see that ProcessExplorer is able to Suspend/Resume/Terminate every thread of each process. So I was wondering if there is a method to Inherit a ThreadHandle from a different Process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can get the handle of the originating process, you can use [DuplicateHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251%28VS.85%29.aspx) to create a handle to any kernel object within that process that you have access to.